# Something I am missing with many to many relationship in android room database

Tags: android, relational-database, android-room, one-to-many, android-architecture-components

Following the official documentation for using @Relation and Junction tables for cross relationship between two tables and I am not having good results.

I am using these two entities:

```
@Entity(tableName = "Dog",
foreignKeys = arrayOf(
    ForeignKey(entity = Owner::class,
        parentColumns = arrayOf("ownerId"),
        childColumns = arrayOf("dogOwnerId"))
))
data class Dog(
@PrimaryKey val dogId: Long,
val dogOwnerId: Long,
val name: String,
val cuteness: Int,
val barkVolume: Int,
val breed: String
)

@Entity
data class Owner(@PrimaryKey val ownerId: Long, val name: String)
```

using this table to join them

```
@Entity(primaryKeys = ["dogId", "ownerId"])
data class DogOwnerCrossRef(
val dogId: Long,
val ownerId: Long
)
```

and this class for the **Query response**:

```
data class DogWithOwners(
@Embedded val dog: Dog,
@Relation(
    parentColumn = "dogId",
    entity = Owner::class,
    entityColumn = "ownerId",
    associateBy = Junction(DogOwnerCrossRef::class)
)
val owners: List<Owner>
)
```

My **DAO**:

```
  @Transaction
  @Query("SELECT * FROM Dog")
  fun getdogWithOwners(): List<DogWithOwners>
```

the result is always null for Owner objects which looks like the @Transaction haven't been made,I am puzzled on how to handle this query without making any join queries.

Comment: FWIW, I have an example of a many-to-many relation in Room [here](https://gitlab.com/commonsguy/cw-room/-/tree/v0.2/MiscSamples/src/main/java/com/commonsware/room/misc/manytomany).

Comment: Thanks for the example,for how i understand it ,i need to insert in bookCategoryJoin using @insert in DAO before i can load data from it, when what i need is to have a reference between book and category(every book refer to a category and every category refer to different books) and that join the two table in one table for me when i require it , is that possible ?

Comment: If you are asking whether a category can have no books, and whether a book can have no categories, then the answer is yes. Those entities would not have corresponding join entities. You only insert join entities when you have two entities that need to be joined.